# When I draw an ellipse on mouse position it gets drawn correct but when I move it, it moves to the corner of the window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

when I move my ellipse it slides to the top left corner of the window, or in random places, sometimes it goes to -ve points. I don't know why it moves but at the same time it gets drawn in the correct mouse position.

I also tried to return it to the mouse position in the mouseReleaseEvent, but it gets to the random point first then gets back to the mouse position

```
class Draw(QMainWindow):
    base=[]
    molecular=[]
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        loadUi("drawnetwork.ui",self)
        self.scene=QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(126,0,652,379)
        
        self.gview.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gview.show()
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
      
        if(x>127):
            if(self.drawbase.isChecked()):
               
                posx=event.pos().x()
                posy=event.pos().y()
                radius=20
                color=QBrush(Qt.green)
                myellipse=NodeEllipse(posx,posy,radius,color,"first")
                self.base.append(myellipse)
                self.scene.addItem(myellipse)
class NodeEllipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    isPressed=False
    pozx=0
    pozy=0
    
   
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self,posx,posy,r,color,name):
        super().__init__(posx, posy, r, r)
       
       # self.setPos(posx,posy)
        self.pozx=posx
        self.pozy=posy
       
        self.setBrush(color)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable)
        #self.setFlag(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("i am pressed or not")
        print(self.isPressed)
        self.isPressed=True


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print("i am released")
        print('x: {0}, y: {1}'.format(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y()))    
        if(self.isPressed):
            self.setPos(event.pos().x(),event.pos().y())
           
            self.isPressed=False
```

Comment: your question is unclear, What is your goal?

Comment: @mdl as already told you in your previous question: 1. you must *not* override `mousePressEvent()` in the main window, but in the object that is expected to receive that event, which is the QGraphicsView or the QGraphicsScene shown in it; 2. you should not create class attributes with mutable types like dict or list. Also, the `posx` and `posy` you're using are the position of the *drawn* ellipse relative to the *item position* (which by default is always 0, 0 for all items).

Answer (score 1):

I see unnecessary to override the mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent methods, also the positions you use are relative to the item but setPos expects positions relative to the scene which explains the incorrect positions:

```py
class NodeEllipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, r, color, name):
        super().__init__(-r / 2, -r / 2, r, r)
        self.setBrush(color)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPos(posx, posy)


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        pos = event.scenePos()
        has_item = bool(self.itemAt(pos, QTransform()))
        if not has_item:
            radius = 20
            color = QBrush(Qt.green)
            myellipse = NodeEllipse(pos.x(), pos.y(), radius, color, "first")
            self.addItem(myellipse)
```

```
self.scene = GraphicsScene()
self.scene.setSceneRect(126, 0, 652, 379)
self.gview.setScene(self.scene)
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I need to draw the ellipse if a certain checkbox, which is in the Draw(QMainWindow) class, but I can't access it from the GraphicScene class

Comment: I also tried your answer it draws in the correct position, but the problem occurs when I move the ellipse it slides to the position (0,0)